# Do we use a comma or not when using several adjectives?

Tags: commas

> He is a deranged fanatical and stupid person.
>
> He is a deranged, fanatical and stupid person.

I am not sure if you have to use a comma or not when we have only 2 adjectives we don't use any comma, but when using three, I am not sure the same rule applies.

> It's a big red shoe.
>
> It's a big red and dirty shoe.

Comment: Whoever told you that we don't use a comma with only two adjectives told you a big, fat lie. Using a comma is more typical than using "and".

Comment: By editing this question, you've made it exceedingly more difficult to answer. In fact, the distinction between *big red shoe* and *big, red shoe* has nothing to do with what you'd originally written. If I hadn't already answered, I would now vote to close this because you are asking at least two different things at once. (As demonstrated by another answer that only addresses the second question you now have.)

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm learning English.

I learned recently from a video that if you can swap the 2 adjectives (because their order doesn't matter), then a comma is needed. For example, "a long, thin pole", "a nice red car". Here, long and thin are of the same category so you can swap them, hence a comma is needed; you won't separate nice and red with a comma because nice should always come before red.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: The first part of this answer addresses the original question, before it was edited. The newly added *big red shoe* is something quite different, and actually a separate question.

---

Yes, you either need the first comma or an additional conjunction:

- He is a deranged, fanatical and stupid person.
- He is a deranged and fanatical and stupid person.

Without the first comma or another conjunction, it violates the normal convention of conjunctions of three or more items.

It also looks like a typo involving a missing hyphen for only two adjectives:

> ？ He is a deranged-fanatical and stupid person.
> → He is a deranged-fanatical person ***and a*** stupid person.

---

However, the sentence as a whole is written in an order that makes it look very strange. This particular set of adjectives and noun is seldom used in this way.

Personally, I would remove the article and noun:

- He is deranged, fanatical, and stupid.

Or I would move *person* towards the start of the sentence:

- He is a person *who is* deranged, fanatical, and stupid.

Note that I added a serial comma at the end, but that's a matter of style. (However, I do think it helps illustrate the specific point being made here.)